# PHP email code showing in browser and not sending email

Tags: php, html, email

I've made a form in html which has a submit button on at the bottom of the form and when that it pressed it should go to the PHP file and then grab the data from the form to then send it to my email but when I press submit it just brings the PHP code up on the screen. This is the html code:

```
<div id="form">
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Name:</label>
</br>
</br>
<span><input type="text" name="firstname"></span></br>
<label>Email:</label>
</br>
</br>   
<span><input type="text" name="email"></span></br>
<label>Subject:</label>
</br>  
</br>
<span><input type="text" name="subject"></span></br>
<label>Message:</label>
</br>
</br>  
<span><textarea name="myText" cols="46" rows="10"></textarea></span>
</br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" formaction="form.php">
</form>
</div>
```

The code is within a div so I can style it later in CSS. This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$myemail = "myemail@hotmail.co.uk";

$firname = $_POST['firstname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$myText = $_POST['myText'];

mail($myemail,$subject,$myText,$headers);
?>
```

I am completely new to PHP so I don't know what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Does the file have a .php extension? Does your host offer PHP?

Comment: Are you testing locally? Seems that PHP is not installed on the server.

Comment: Yes it does and I don't know what that means, sorry. Could you possibly explain? @JohnConde

Comment: Why do you set `form action=""` and use `value="Submit" formaction="form.php"` ?

Comment: create a new php page and just write
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
If it displays php info, you have it installed, if not you need to install it.

Comment: Add `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to top of the page and see if you get results. If not, then you don't have PHP installed.

Comment: Remove `formaction="form.php"` then use `<form action="form.php" method="post">` instead of `<form action="" method="post">` that should fix it.

Comment: I did put `form action"form.php"` and then I deleted that and put in `formaction="form.php"` to see if it made a difference. @DainisAbols

Comment: Then create a file called "test.php" with this inside, see if anything comes up `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` you "should" get a bunch of server PHP info. If the same thing occurs, then PHP is not installed.

Comment: Btw, are you running this on your own computer `localhost`, or via WWW?

Comment: Do I open the "test.php" file in my browser? If so all that comes up on the screen is `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`@Fred-ii-

Comment: I'm running it on my own computer so `localhost` @Fred-ii-

Comment: Yes, it needs to run from your browser. Did you upload it to your server? Are you doing this on a hosted or localhost?

Comment: Well then, your PHP is either NOT installed, or is not properly configured. Did you install PHP, or are you expecting this to run like a regular web page?

Comment: I opened it with my browser and all that came up was `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and localhost @Fred-ii-

Comment: Don't expect to run a PHP file like a regular `.html` file (web page). That's most likely what's going on here.

Comment: Well I have no idea how php works. I assumed it worked exactly the same as html would but obviously not. How do I install PHP? @Fred-ii-

Comment: An easy way to install PHP is by installing [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) (on Windows) or [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) (on Mac)

Comment: No, `.php` files doesn't just "RUN" like a regular web page would. It (PHP) needs to be "installed" and running before you can "execute" it.

Comment: See what `Casper André Casse` wrote in a comment. I can't be of any further help.

Comment: Get yourself a (free) hosting service with `mail()` and upload it there. That will work until you install PHP on your machine.

Comment: Where is `$headers` defined?

Comment: Did any of the answers lead you to a solution? @user2387537

Answer (score 0):

It seems PHP is not installed on your computer.

Try to install:

[XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) for Windows

or

[MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) for Mac

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the form action to the script

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
```

Comment: not necessary. if not set it will send the form to the current page

Comment: If posting to the current page I prefer to leave action empty. If you don't leave action empty you will have to change it every time you add/remove GET parameters or rename your script.

Comment: Well it seems it's not the same page, so he does need to specify the url of the script. anyways, the php is not enabled on the server if you see the content of php file.

Comment: One more thing: your design is wrong if you change the script name so often.